# The office open XML file cannot be open because there are problems with the content

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to send a msword file as attachment without storing the document on the hard disk, but if  is specify the document as a text file i.e notepad, it works very fine. But if the attachment is specified as a word document, the document will be attached and sent, but it will open with an error message "The office open XML file cannot be open because there are problems with the content" Can someone please help me

```
Sub sendattachment(S as Object,E as EventArgs)
dim EmailMessage as string = "Dear "& firstname.text &"<br>, Please find  attached <br><br>Thank you"
Dim strFrom = "me<support@mymail.com>"
Dim strTo = username.text 
Dim MailMsg As New MailMessage(New MailAddress(strFrom.Trim()), New MailAddress(strTo))  
MailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default  
MailMsg.Subject = " Subject"
MailMsg.Body = EmailMessage
MailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High  
MailMsg.IsBodyHtml = True  
'Smtpclient to send the mail message  
Dim SmtpMail As New SmtpClient  
Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New system.Net.NetworkCredential("me@theemail.com", "thepassword") 

'Get some binary data
Dim data As Byte() = GetData()
'save the data to a memory stream
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
'create the attachment from a stream. Be sure to name the data with a file and file type
```

MailMsg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(ms, "filename.docx", "application/msword"))
    SmtpMail.Host = "mail.myemail.com"
    SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SmtpMail.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo

```
SmtpMail.Send(MailMsg)  

end sub

Function GetData() As Byte()
Dim s As String = "this is some text"
Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)
Return data
End Function 'GetData
```

Comment: Where does the `stream` variable come from? Why are you doing two attachments? You're encoding a string as ASCII, putting it in a byte array, and attaching that to the email. A `.docx` file is not just some ASCII characters. Perhaps you should do some more research into what an actual `.docx` file looks like.

Comment: the **stream** variable and the second attachment was an error and it has been corrected. Kindly help

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, you're not generating a valid `.docx` file. You're generating a text file. A `.docx` file is not a text file. A `.docx` file is a zipped directory containing XML files and other resources. To generate a valid `.docx` file in .NET, you need to find a library capable of generating one for you.

Comment: Okay. but, a .docx is suppose to be a microsoft word file

Comment: Yes, `.docx` is the usual format used by Microsoft Word. But that doesn't change anything I said in my previous comments. It's still not valid to provide a text file. If you want to provide a text file, then change the extension to `.txt`.

Comment: okay. Thank you very much. i really appreciate. I am working on it as you suggested